# Mod_rewrite AH00124 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to create a rewrite rule so that

```
http://domain.ext/truc.php?id=value
```

would map to

```
http://domain.ext/value
```

so i wrote this rule in .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /truc.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But that gives a permanent 500 error.

logs tell this :

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

anyone to help, please :) ManyThx

Thierry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is an infinite loop here since your rule is constantly routing to `/p.php`. Use a `RewriteCond` to prevent it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ p.php?linkID=$1 [L,QSA]
```